# DNS settings don't work in Docker CE

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dns

I use Docker in a corporate environment where a custom DNS server is required to access the internet. So I have the following set in `/etc/default/docker`:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns <some IP> --dns <some other IP>"
```

This works fine with the Docker version shipped by my distro (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802
```

These IP addresses are in `/etc/resolv.conf`, as I expect.

However, it does not work if I install the latest stable Docker CE (as described at https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/), with the following version:

```
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
```

The docker configuration file is not changed. When apt asks whether to overwrite it, I choose no, and checked that yes, the configuration file is the same. However, when I run a container, I find the following entries in `resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Obviously, the network doesn't work as I expect. What could have possibly gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use json config instead. Create this file if it doesn't exist: `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{"dns": ["<some-ip>", "<other-ip>"]}
```

Then restart the docker service. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file) for further info.